# Bad time delay computed for comments on SO

Tags: bug

In the question ["Converting an array implementation into a linked list ADT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240419/converting-an-array-implementation-into-a-linked-list-adt), the delay displayed **'18 hours ago'** are not corresponding to the real duration.

The timedate of the comment is **'2017-02-15 04:00:22Z'** and the now is **'2017-02-16 19:34:00Z'** corresponding to a delay of **'39 hours ago'** instead of the displayed **'18 hours ago'**.

The last comment has been recorded at **'2017-02-15 11:18:28Z'** and from now **'2017-02-16 19:34:00Z'** that represents **'32 hours ago'** instead of the displayed **'23 hours ago'**.

Is there a mismatch with timezone ?

[image]

Comment: I'm getting "yesterday" (the "delay" shown for between 24 & 48 hours ago) for all three of those comments. Are you sure it's not caching?

Comment: Looks good to me, force a browser refresh please.  Watch out for the back button displaying stale page content.  And always mention what browser you use.

Comment: Humm, you are both right, after refreshing the post, the delay is "yesterday".

Comment: I'd say either caching on your end, or could you have, perhaps, left the post open overnight or something?

Comment: @Kendra, my doubt was coming from displayed delays which are refreshed independently, but not using the same timedate source ? Very strange to see my comment older than the 2 previous !!!